# How to update object based off objects specific value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 objects and I want to 'transplant' values from one object into the other.

The first object I am drawing data from looks like:

```
var userData = {
  Data: [
    {
      Amount: 430140.68,
      Year: "2015",
      AccountName: "Account 1"
    },
    {
      Amount: 458997.32,
      Year: "2016",
      Name: "Account 2"
    },
  ]
}
```

The 2nd object I am placing data into looks like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Account 1",
        "data": [
            0,
            0
        ],
    },
    {
        "name": "Account 2",
        "data": [
            0,
            0
        ],
    }
]
```

My goal is to take the `Amount` form the first object and place it in the `data` array of the 2nd. Each year corresponds to a value in the 'data` array.

So, the resulting updated object should look like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Account 1",
        "data": [
            430140.68,
            0
        ],
    },
    {
        "name": "Account 2",
        "data": [
            0,
            458997.32
        ],
    }
]
```

To try to achieve this I have the following code:

```
const yearArrLength = yearsArr.length;
const generatedObj = new Array(yearArrLength).fill(0);
// Push name and populate data array with 0s.
for (var key of Object.keys(userData.Data)) {
    var accName = userData.Data[key].AccountName;
    if (!generatedObj.find(key => key.name === accName)){
        generatedObj.push({'name': accName, 'data': blankDataArr});
    }
}

for (var key of Object.keys(userData.Data)) {
    var accName = userData.Data[key].AccountName;
    var accAmount = userData.Data[key].Amount;
    var accYear = userData.Data[key].Year;

    // Get location of years array value
    var yearArrIndex = yearsArr.indexOf(accYear);

    for (var key of Object.keys(generatedObj)) {
        if (generatedObj[key].name == accName) {
            generatedObj[key].data[yearArrIndex] = accAmount;
        }
    }

}
```

However, this seems to populate all of the data array values, eg:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Account 1",
        "data": [
            430140.68,
            458997.32
        ],
    },
    {
        "name": "Account 2",
        "data": [
            430140.68,
            458997.32
        ],
    }
]
```

I'm completely stumped as to why. The `if` statement should be checking if there is a matching account name, but it doesn't seem to fire.

Would anyone know what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're pushing the exact same `blankDataArr` each time - you're not pushing a *new* array, you're pushing the *same* array to all.

For a more minimal example:

```js
const subarr = [];

const arr = [subarr, subarr];
arr[0].push('x');
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));

// both items in `arr` have changed
// because both refer to the exact same subarr object
```

For what you're trying to do, it looks like it'd be a lot easier to make an object or Map indexed by `AccountName` first, that way you just have to access or create the `AccountName` property while iterating, and assign to the appropriate year.

```js
const yearsArr = ['2015', '2016'];
const userData = {
  Data: [
    {
      Amount: 430140.68,
      Year: "2015",
      AccountName: "Account 1"
    },
    {
      Amount: 458997.32,
      Year: "2016",
      AccountName: "Account 2"
    },
  ]
};

const dataByAccountName = new Map();
for (const { AccountName, Amount, Year } of userData.Data) {
  if (!dataByAccountName.has(AccountName)) {
    // Create an entirely new array:
    dataByAccountName.set(AccountName, yearsArr.map(() => 0));
  }
  const index = yearsArr.indexOf(Year);
  dataByAccountName.get(AccountName)[index] = Amount;
}
const result = [...dataByAccountName.entries()].map(([name, data]) => ({ name, data }));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Sorry, I'm not good at ES6 at all. How would I add more (static) data to the new object? Eg: I need to add `"type": "bar"` to each. I tried a few ways but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Can't say for sure without knowing exactly what sort of data, but perhaps you just need to add a property or few to the object returned in the final `.map`? `({ name, data })` to `({ name, data, someOtherProp })` or `({ name, data, type: 'bar' })`